# Found an old solution managed with TFS (centralised) - easy enough to get into git?

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, bitbucket

As title says, I have stumbled across a solution of over 25 projects. In each project folder is dev, main and release folders (the TFS branches that were used at the time).

I'd like to bring this into git/bitbucket instead.

I'm not convinced my approach of manually pulling out the code from each 'main' or 'release' branch and restructuring the solution folder is the most efficient. Is there some tool that makes light work of this? I guess what I'm asking is whether there is a nice way to port over a solution from centralised TFS to bitbucket?

### EDIT

I should add, I am not bothered about the commit history of this solution and the contained projects. I am happy to lose all of that - we don't even have Visual Studio on the machine, it is (at the moment) just on disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution named `git-tfs bridge`, which is able to 
port your TFVC files to any git repo.

The bigger your TFVC repo is, the longer the transformation is going
to take. My TFVC repos had 3 years worth of work, branches and commits, 
and the transformation took 3 hours.

Please check https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs

If you just want to import a new project onto your bitbucket, then you have to:
(info from https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html):

> Assuming you have Git installed on your local machine, then:
>
> 1. Locally, change to the root directory of your existing source.
> 2. Initialize the project by running the following commands in the terminal:
>
> ```
>     git init
>     git add --all
>     git commit -m "Initial Commit"
> ```
>
> 3. Log into Bitbucket Server and create a new repository.
> 4. Locate the clone URL in the nav panel on the left (for example:  https://username@your.bitbucket.domain:7999/yourproject/repo.git).
> 5. Push your files to the repository by running the following commands in the terminal (change the URL accordingly):
>
> ```
> git remote add origin https://username@your.bitbucket.domain:7999/yourproject/repo.git 
> git push -u origin master
> ```
>
> Done! Your repository is now available in Bitbucket Server.

Comment: With this solution, you can specify whether you want the whole history, or just the latest version of your files.

Comment: Another option is just to make a `git init` in your workdir, make an "initial" commit, add another remote and then push the whole set of files into your new git repo.